# Why does systemctl lists wheel users when making a change

Tags: linux, arch-linux, systemctl

Whenever I start a service with `systemctl` without specifying `sudo`, it displays a list of wheel users and prompts me to select one.

I simply want to start the service from my user without seeing the list of wheel users.

Is there a way to prompt me for my password instead?

Answer (score 1):

Try the `--user` option:

```
systemctl --user start myservice
```

Otherwise `systemctl` will assume you want to control system level services which may require the use of one of those `wheel` users.